# How can I stop receiving blank data from being inserted into my database?

Tags: php, mysql

On our website there is a signup form where a user can subscribe to our newsletter. The form has a first and last name field, email address field, city, state and country field. When subscribers signup for the list, they are then inserted into a database.

Sometimes we'll receive phantom, or blank email "signups" with no information inserted into our database, despite the fact 3 out of the 6 fields are required. I've realized recently that simply opening the php file in Dreamweaver will prompt a hit to the database with blank info.

The email address that always comes through is one that is familiar. We use Godaddy for hosting and are hosting two sites, the second site is the one that is in question, and the email address that hits the database is from the first site.

Is there any way to stop these phantom emails?

Here is my php code:

```
<?php

define('DB_NAME', '');
define('DB_USER', '');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_HOST', '');

$first = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['First']));
$last = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Last']));
$city = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['City']));
$state = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['State']));
$country = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Country']));
$email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email']));
$tempt = $_POST['tempt'];
$tempt2 = $_POST['tempt2'];


if ($tempt == 'http://' && empty($tempt2)) {

    $error_message = '';
    $reg_exp = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9­-]+\.[a-zA-Z.]{2,5}$/";

    if(!preg_match($reg_exp, $email)) {

        $error_message .= "<p>A valid email address is required.</p>";
    }
    if (empty($first)) {
        $error_message .= "<p>Please provide your first name.</p>";
    }
    if (empty($last)) {
        $error_message .= "<p>Please provide your last name.</p>";
    }

    if (!empty($error_message)) {

        $return['error'] = true;
        $return['msg'] = "<p>The request was successful, but the form was not filled out correctly.</p>".$error_message;
        echo json_encode($return);
        exit();

    } else {

        $return['error'] = false;
        $return['msg'] = "<p style='top:9px; color:#ff6000; left:63px; text-align:left; font-size:1.50em;'>".$first .", <p style='top:0px; width:100%; left:63px; text-align:left; line-height:1.1em;'>your subscription request has been processed.</p>";
        echo json_encode($return);
    }

} else {

        $return['error'] = true;
        $return['msg'] = "<p>There was a problem while sending this form. Try it again.</p>";
        echo json_encode($return);
}


$to = "3elementsreview@gmail.com, marlonfowler@yahoo.com";
$subject = "New Email Address for Mailing List";
$headers = "From: $email\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

$message = "<span style='color:#252525; font-size:1.2em;'>A visitor to 3Elements Review has entered the following information so they can be added to your mailing list.</span><br>\n
<br>
<span style='color:#252525; font-weight:bold; font-size:1.35em;'>$first $last</span><br>
<span style='color:#252525; font-weight:bold; font-size:1.35em;'>$city, $state</span><br>
<span style='color:#252525; font-weight:bold; font-size:1.35em;'>$country</span><br>
<span style='color:#252525; font-weight:bold; font-size:1.35em;'>$email</span>";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);





mail($user,$usersubject,$usermessage,$userheaders);




$link = mysql_connect('xxxx.somedomain.com', 'myusername', 'mypassword');

if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db('mefowler', $link);

if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Can\'t use ' . 'mefowler' . ': ' . mysql_error());
}

$value = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['First']);
$value2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Last']);
$value3 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['City']);
$value4 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['State']);
$value5 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Country']);
$value6 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Email']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO members (First, Last, City, State, Country, Email, Date) VALUES('$value','$value2','$value3','$value4','$value5','$value6',NOW() + interval 2 hour)";

if (!mysql_query($sql)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_close();

?>






HTML -------->
<form class="contact-me" action="php-signup/sign-up-complete.php" method="post" name="contact-me">
<div id="response2"><!-----------------CONTAINS FORM ERROR MESSAGE--------------></div>

<input name="First" pattern="[A-Za-z]{2,15}" title="Your First Name is Required" id="first" autofocus placeholder="First Name" type="text" maxlength="15"></input><br>
<input name="Last" pattern="[A-Za-z]{2,15}" title="Your Last Name is Required" id="last" placeholder="Last Name" type="text" maxlength="15"></input><br>
<input name="Email" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9\@\.com]{7,50}" title="Your E-Mail Address is Required" id="email" placeholder="E-Mail Address" type="email" maxlength="50"></input><br>
<input name="City" pattern="[A-Za-z\s]{3,40}" id="city" title="Please fill in your 'City'" placeholder="City" type="text" maxlength="40"></input><br>
```

Comment: i would suggest to remove the login details of ur db if they are real.

Comment: Use JS on the front end to check all fields are complete. Verify with PHP on the back end.

Comment: No email eh? Make it `die()`

Comment: You should update all your accounts that use that password.

Comment: ...or just delete this question altogether and start over.

Comment: Could you only post relevant parts of your code?

Comment: The code is now condensed.

Comment: Doesn't matter. It will still show up in the edit(s). @MarlonFowler - So do as [`Kyle suggested.`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053409/how-can-i-stop-receiving-blank-data-from-being-inserted-into-my-database#comment33439109_22053409)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just stop the script from running if the page wasn't posted to.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
//put code here}
else {}
```

Comment: Keaner, I believe this is working. Thanks a whole lot.